# Accessing a static file in django from a filename in a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm writing an application that obtains a filename from a database and outputs the associated image.  However, django templates seems to be having trouble parsing my requests

Here is the django view:

```
def nii2(request):
    conn_str_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                                 'connection_string.txt')
    connection_string = open(conn_str_file).read()
    cursor = db.connect(connection_string).cursor()
    sql = '''
    SELECT img.[djangoFileLoc]
    FROM [image_locations$] img,
    [Metadata$] meta
    WHERE img.[originalFileName] = meta.[originalFileName]
    '''
    if 'Machine' in request.GET:
        sql += 'AND Machine = %r' % request.GET['Machine']
    if 'Dir' in request.GET:
        if request.GET['Dir'] != 'Both':
            sql += ' AND Dir = %r' % request.GET['Dir']
    sql += ' ORDER BY img.[originalFileName]'
    djangoImages = []
    sql += ';'
    data = cursor.execute(sql)
    for row in data:
        djangoImages.append(row[0])
    context = {"imageLoc": djangoImages[0:21]}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Here is template.html:

```html
{% extends "images.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block images %}
{% for img in imageLoc %}
<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('{% static '{{img}}' %}', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='{% static '{{img}}' %}' title ="Image 1"/></a> 

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is what the output source comes out as:

```html
<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a> 


<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='/static/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D' title ="Image 1"/></a>
```

So instead of inserting the file name from the list it just reads the variable.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

After a week of thinking about this, braking down and posting the question here, the solution finally occurred to me after I posted.  I just removed the brackets around the variable:

```html
{% extends "images.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block images %}
{% for img in imageLoc %}
<a><img onmouseover="previewFunction('{% static img %}', 'Image One', 'Detailed info on Image one')"
                src='{% static img %}' title ="Image 1"/></a> 

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```